# Google Adsense, CORS and Rails in Safari dumps thousands of console errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cross-domain, adsense

I am serving google ads on an SSL site successfully, with CORS headers set properly (and wide open) by [`rack-cors`](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) as:

```
Rails.configuration.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins  '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: :any
  end
end
```

I can confirm that the headers are there with a curl call:

```
$ curl -I https://viewing.nyc -H "Origin: https://foobar.com"
...
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foobar.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
...
```

If you visit in Chrome or Firefox, there are no cross-site scripting errors in the console, yet on Safari, there are thousands.

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net" from accessing a frame with origin "https://viewing.nyc". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

[Live example](https://viewing.nyc)

I've poured through the `rack-cors` issues page with no solution working thus far. Why is this happening **only on Safari**, and how can I fix it?

Comment: As an added bonus, I will also award a 500 bounty on this similar question from 2 years ago, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858447/ssl-custom-tlds-crossdomain-xml-and-adsense-can-they-play-nicely, and award it to the bounty hunter  of this question, if solved.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using Sierra with the latest Safari version ?

Comment: yes, sierra with latest, though the problem has persisted for years: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858447/ssl-custom-tlds-crossdomain-xml-and-adsense-can-they-play-nicely

Comment: @coneybeare, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2542166/3863146) on SO explains why the console error messages appear.

Comment: I've seen that, but it's from 2010

Comment: I checked a little what happens on Safari. I modified some HTTP responses with [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/). You can create a Python script and feed it to mitmproxy to replace headers on the fly. I messed up a little with CSP, adding `Content-Security-Policy`, `X-Content-Security-Policy` and `X-WebKit-CSP` to the response, but without success. I also checked briefly on chrome and I have a couple of error messages in the console: `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` related to advertisement scripts.

Comment: I did try a generous CSP without success too: http://cloud.coneybeare.me/i1YN

Answer (score 1):

I think adding content-security-policy headers should help you.

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net
```

Read More Here:-

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/

Comment: I implemented a CSP with the appropriate headers, alas no fix for this issue. http://cloud.coneybeare.me/i1YN

Comment: I know this is old, but... Was your ad inside an iFrame?

Answer (score -1):

This topic (the last answer) states that it should work despite errors. Safari is sensitive to such differences.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ima-sdk/AxE9vZith00

> skippable ads are not supported on iPhone devices and that's why you
>   are experiencing issues with ad playback.  I'd suggest adding
>   additional mimeTypes to your tag in order to support use cases across
>   all devices.
>
> As for the error that you originally were experiencing, "Blocked a
>   frame with origin "http://imasdk.googleapis.com" from accessing a
>   frame with origin "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx". Protocols, domains, and
>   ports must match.", we have seen this error before and as you stated
>   it should not affect ad playback.  The explanation of this error is a
>   same-origin policy restriction that is disallowing one domain from
>   accessing resources from a different domain.  It is blocking
>   Cross-Origin Resources from being shared.  You can update your CORS
>   headers, as outlined in our documentation, to allow cross-origin
>   sharing.

Comment: Well, yes, this is the question. I have updated my CORS headers as shown above, but am still seeing the issue. This answer just rephrases my question. Ads work, but asking me to simply ignore these 1000's of errors is not an acceptable solution.